# Why the Eslint in Inttellij given me a carrels lines under some of the keywords used in my code. Mac Laptop

Tags: intellij-idea

[This how it show me in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPEHa.png) I am using this code in my IntelliJ, but I am using Eslint style for my code, and 
it gives me carrels lines under some of the keywords like " describe, 
it,.to.have.all.members" which I don't know why even though I download Mocha and 
Chai as well anyone had this problem.

```
describe('Test for Performance', function () {
it('maxPrimeSum(10000) should take <= 20ms', function () {
this.timeout(20);
chai.expect(maxPrimeSum(10000)).to.have.all.members([9521, 65]);
 });
  it('maxPrimeSum(100000) should take <= 200ms', function () {
  this.timeout(200);
  chai.expect(maxPrimeSum(100000)).to.have.all.members([92951, 183]);
});
```

});

Comment: are you sure these are eslint errors? please hover over highlighted lines to see error tooltips and take screenshots of them

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but it shows that it does not know the keyword and it says i should create a method for it.

Comment: You can see the picture. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try installing chai & mocha typescript stubs (`npm i @types/chai @types/mocha --save`, or **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries, Download...**). This can also be done via intention, on `Alt+Enter` - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.